# How can I log poorly written SQL queries on production

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is a [patently bad SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/16386953#16386953):

```
SELECT DISTINCT MIN(id), customer, total FROM purchases GROUP BY (customer)
```

It works today and it will break sometime when we migrate databases or upgrade the server. If it works today, I'm sure my production application is littered with examples like this and worse.

We can stop the above example by enabling the MySQL sql_mode [`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-mode.html) or even [`ANSI`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi) mode. But of course we can't do this on production. We could set up a dev server, change to ANSI mode, and run a code completion test... also not attractive.

Is there a way to allow MySQL to run the way we know and love it... while also logging queries like the above which are not ANSI (or are in some other way not high quality)?

Comment: Are you not removing that elephant from the living room, just trying to learn how to ignore it?

Comment: Would like to find all elephants and plan for their removal... rather than start a stampede in my fragile house

Comment: Turn you house in a wild life reserve and ticket for admittance =). Serious now if you plan to remove that messy later it's ok but that usually at IT shops that later turns on never really fast

Comment: You cant detect half-assed queries™ but you can use https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/mysql/slow-query-log/